# Is It Possible To Embed SDL2 In An Application Without Building It As A Library?

Tags: c++, c, embed, sdl-2, gyp

Is it possible to use SDL2 from source in an application, without needing to compile .libs, .dlls or OSX frameworks files?

My C/C++ skills can be best described as naive, but I suspect the library can be used in this way. Has anyone done so successfully, or tried something similar?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible compile them together, but SDL2 has many dependencies and some really complicated build steps that it is not for beginners. And the building time is longer, so better compiling that separated anyway.